# Como ter uma mesma margem para todas as linhas do texto:

Tags: html, css

Quero deixar meu texto com a mesma margem que está sendo usada na tag `<b>`

```html
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
 <title>Harley Davidson</title>
 <style>
 div#interface {
 width: 1200px;
 margin: auto;
 }
 b {
 margin-left: 30px;
 }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="interface">

<p><b>História:</b> <i>Com efeito, um dia, um rapaz inteligente, farto de ter de pedalar, teve a ideia genial de acrescentar um motor à sua bicicleta. Foi exatamente isso que aconteceu a dois americanos, colegas de universidade, Arthur Davidson e William S. Harley, respetivamente escultor e desenhista, que se lançaram nessa arriscada união. Se bem que tenham tido o cuidado de associar aos seus trabalhos Ole Evinrude, um motorista, a primeira máquina assim criada, entre outros detalhes, a lenda diz que o carburador era feito de uma lata em conservas - foi uma falha completa: o engenho recusou-se terminantemente a andar. O motor, demasiado fraco, não conseguiu proporcionar o conjunto.</i></p>

</div>
```

Caso ainda não dê pra entender, o que eu quero fazer é alinhar o texto dessa forma (sendo a linha preta onde quero alinhar):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em vez de atribuíres a `margin-left: 30px;` para a tag `<b>`, atribui para o `<p>` que é a tag que contém todo o texto.

```
p { margin-left: 30px;}
```

Ao definires `b { margin-left: 30px;}` no CSS, estás a dizer que queres que o elemento com a tag `<b>` tenha uma margem de `30px` da margem esquerda, logo se ao invés disso atribuíres este estilo CSS ao `<p>`, estás a atribuir esse estilo para todo o bloco de texto, pois é a tag `<p>` que está a 'segurar' todo o bloco de texto.

Exemplo abaixo:

```css
div#interface {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
}
p {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <b>História:</b>
  <i>Com efeito, um dia, um rapaz inteligente, farto de ter de pedalar, teve a ideia genial de acrescentar um motor à sua bicicleta. Foi exatamente isso que aconteceu a dois americanos, colegas de universidade, Arthur Davidson e William S. Harley, respetivamente escultor e desenhista, que se lançaram nessa arriscada união. Se bem que tenham tido o cuidado de associar aos seus trabalhos Ole Evinrude, um motorista, a primeira máquina assim criada, entre outros detalhes, a lenda diz que o carburador era feito de uma lata em conservas - foi uma falha completa: o engenho recusou-se terminantemente a andar. O motor, demasiado fraco, não conseguiu proporcionar o conjunto.</i>
</p>
```

Comment: Mas quero meu texto em negrito, existe outro jeito de deixar meu texto em negrito sem ser com a tag `<b>`?

Comment: O texto fica a negrito na mesma, não é por isto que ele vai deixar de ficar a negrito como podes ver no exemplo que postei clicando no botão `► Executar trecho de código`, pois o que foi mudado foi apenas o estilo `margin-left: 30px;` que agora vai passar a ser implementado no `<p>`, em vez do `<b>`.

Comment: Podes e deves utilizar o `<b>` para deixar texto a negrito, mas **Sim**, podias deixar o texto a negrito de outra forma, como por exemplo criando uma classe especifica para isso da seguinte forma: CSS - `.negrito{font-weight:bold;}` e no HTML - `<span class="negrito">texto a negrito</span>`

Comment: Muito obrigado, me ajudou bastante!